# kaltura multiple players on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-player, kaltura

I am trying to embed more than one players on the same page, but that has no success until now. In order to embed the player we need a unique target_id to target the element of the DOM and then the entry_id of the specific video. This is done in the following function:

```
function embedPlayer() {
  var linkPart = $('#uniqueTarget').data('entry');
  var conf = {
    "targetId": "uniqueTarget",
    "wid": "_1912616",
    "uiconf_id": "37591811",
    "entry_id": linkPart,
    "flashvars": {
      "controlBarContainer.plugin": false,
      "inlineScript": false
    }
  };
  kWidget.thumbEmbed(conf);
}
```

Here is the related HTML, which is dynamically created from WordPress every time that the user wants to embed a video:

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
  <div class="theRatio"></div>
  <div id="uniqueTarget" data-entry="'+ linkPart +'" 
       style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately if I try to embed a second player on the same page it will only do the API call for the first player and the second(or the rest, if more) will leave me with plain HTML and the call is not being done. There is an article about the issue at https://knowledge.kaltura.com/javascript-api-kaltura-media-players#ManagingMultiplePlayersontheSamePage, but unfortunately my knowledge is limited and I would need some help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Kaltura recommend using thumb embed when you have multiple players on a page - this will embed thumbnails which will play when they are clicked:

> Thumb Embed
>
> This method takes the same arguments as the dynamic embed. Thumbnail embed passes the entire configuration to the kWidget.embed when the user "clicks" on the play button. This is the recommended method to use when you need to embed multiple players/entries in the same web page. The syntax for ThumbEmbed is identical to kWidget.embed ( dynamic embed ) except we call "kWidget.thumbEmbed" instead of "kWidget.embed"

There is more information including example Javascript and examples thumbnails here:

- http://player.kaltura.com/docs/thumb

Example Javascript from this link (you can also look at the page in a browser debugger to see exactly how they have set it up):

```js
<div id="myEmbedTarget" style="width:400px;height:330px;"></div>
<script src="{{HTML5LibraryURL}}"></script>
<script>
    mw.setConfig("EmbedPlayer.DisableContextMenu",true);
    kWidget.thumbEmbed({
        'targetId': 'myEmbedTarget',
        'wid': '_243342',
        'uiconf_id' : '12905712',
        'entry_id' : '0_uka1msg4',
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create DIV containers for each of your videos - give them unique IDs, then you can target them and create as many videos as you like. Make sure the kWidget script is loaded. Put this script in your page:

```
function _embedVideo(targetId,wid,uiconf_id,flashvars,entry_id,cb){
    kWidget.embed({
        targetId: targetId,
        wid: wid,
        uiconf_id: uiconf_id,
        flashvars: flashvars || {},
        entry_id: entry_id,
        readyCallback: cb
    });
}
```

For each of your videos, load them like so:

```
_embedVideo('id-of-div-container','wid-here','uiconfid-here',null,'entryid-here',yourCallbackFunc);
```

This is how I create multiple videos in my pages. Be sure to specify a callback else pass null.